# How do I compare values in two tables in TSQL Where statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a Stored procedure that accepts a comma delimited string of IDs as a parameter

I have a UDF called Split that then splits that and returns it as a Table

In my query I return a value from a view that is another comma delimited string of IDs

In my Where statement I essentially want to say

```
WHERE dbo.Split(@inputstring) IN dbo.Split(view.ViewString)
```

And only return rows where a value in my input string exists in my View string

How can I best achieve this?

Comment: What is the source of the comma delimited list in the view? Are they actually stored like that or is the View concatenating them then you are splitting them out again? (in which case you are much better off telling us the base tables)

Comment: The view is returning the concatenated IDs as a field using a separate Function then the Split function is breaking them back into a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need select a row if at least one ID from `@inputstring` is in the list `view.ViewString`? If so then:

```
WHERE EXISTS (select ID 
                 from dbo.Split(@inputstring) t1 
                      inner join dbo.Split(view.ViewString) t2 on (t1.id=t2.id))
```